# How to select multiple buttons and display these filtered results dynamically?

Tags: ajax, button, dynamic, expressionengine, categories

I have 9 different categories and I want to select them (by clicking or unclicking a button) and have the results display as I select what I want to see filtered. I have it set up to have 3 different rows and have only 3 categories selected.

How can I do this in EE!? With AJAX? JQuery? How do I even start?

I looked at Isotope, but I am not sure if EE has a way to do this that ties in with the categories selection and displaying results without a submit button.

I have attached a picture what I want to accomplish. (The light gray boxes represent the buttons selected)
Please Help Me!

[image: The boxes on the left are my buttons and the space on the right is where the content will be displayed]

Comment: Will you start with a complete list in your Display Results area, then have the filter clicks remove results? Or will it start blank, and have the filter clicks load new results?

Comment: Yes, I have to start with a complete list of all the results without them being filtered. (it's a database of 540 listings). Yes, they will ALL show in the beginning.

Comment: Could you point me the right direction on how to do this? Low2seg seems to get the URL ID, but what if there's nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jQuery-based solution, but please keep in mind that this only works with javascript. As you mention in your comment, look into LowSeg2Cat for a method of doing this for users with JS disabled as well.

The EE code would look something like this:

```
{!-- List all of your categories --}

{exp:channel:categories channel="stuff" style="linear"}
{if count == "1"}<ul id="categories">{/if}
    <li><a href="#" data-category="{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a></li>
{if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
{/exp:channel:categories}


{!-- List all of your entries --}

{exp:channel:entries channel="stuff" limit="1000"}
{if count == "1"}<ul id="entries">{/if}
    <li data-categories="{categories backspace="1"}{category_url_title} {/categories}">{title}</li>
{if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Here's the javascript that makes it go:

http://jsfiddle.net/5WezD/4/

Answer (score 0):

@Francheska So .. I like introduce you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if you set a demo, code or something to start i'll be great!. Anyways try to check [this](http://delicious.com/desandro/re%3aisotope+fiddle) link.There you got a lot of custom examples.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes I know about jsfiddle, the problem is that I do not know where to even begin with the logic.

Comment: Yes, the jfiddle link you provided is sort of what I want to accomplish. I want to be able to select and narrow down, filter by year, by profession and by letter of alphabet. With different buttons at the top that could be selected with those 3 filters. (In the picture I provided the lighter gray represents the selected buttons) This would narrow down the results, I found out that with Isotope it is not good to have more than 50 listings. I am at a loss!

Comment: @Francheska an example using listbox help? I coul set up one of you want but i need the details of what you wanna filter :/

Comment: Okay - I've created something that I think will help you understand. http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/16/ In there, I've created a small listing. But right now only 1 category could be selected at a time. Like the jpg I posted, I had selected 3 categories at a time (the lighter gray boxes). (so that it is filtered and narrowed down to profession, year, letter of alphabet)

Comment: This looks awesome, but I think each item is only 1 category. Is there a possibility that one of those items is BOTH category 1 and category 2? (Thus narrowing it down)

Comment: Okay! I am actually installing the CMS today!